# AllFramesReady Repeating Loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, loops, kinect

I am creating a program where you do rep of a stretch, so it adds one to amount of reps. I want to have a interval between each rep (not the current problem). I have this nested within the `AllFramesReadyEventArgs`. The problem is, since the SDK uses the `AllFramesReadyEvent` through out the whole program, so it is an infinite loop. How can I do each rep without it repeating when I don't want it to? Thanks in advance.

```
if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
{
    int whereIsX = (int)Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse1);
    int whereToX = (int)Canvas.GetLeft(pspine);
    whatToMultiplyX = whereToX / whereIsX;

    int whereIsY = (int)Canvas.GetTop(ellipse1);
    int whereToY = (int)Canvas.GetTop(pspine);
    whatToMultiplyY = whereToY / whereIsY;

    Canvas.SetTop(ellipse1, Canvas.GetTop(ellipse1) * whatToMultiplyY);
    Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse1, Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse1) * whatToMultiplyX);

    for (int i = 0; i < Doctor_ShoulderX.Count; i++)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(doctorHand, Doctor_HandY[i] * whatToMultiplyY);
        Canvas.SetTop(doctorElbow, Doctor_ElbowY[i] * whatToMultiplyY);
        Canvas.SetTop(doctor_Shoulder, Doctor_ShoulderY[i] * whatToMultiplyY);

        Canvas.SetLeft(doctorHand, Doctor_HandX[i] * whatToMultiplyX);
        Canvas.SetLeft(doctorElbow, Doctor_ElbowX[i] * whatToMultiplyX);
        Canvas.SetLeft(doctor_Shoulder, Doctor_ShoulderX[i] * whatToMultiplyX);                        

        handX = Canvas.GetLeft(handright);
        handY = Canvas.GetTop(handright);

        elbowX = Canvas.GetLeft(elbowright);
        elbowY = Canvas.GetTop(elbowright);

        shoulderX = Canvas.GetLeft(shoulderright);
        shoulderY = Canvas.GetTop(shoulderright);

        shoulder_x.Text = "Shoulder X: " + shoulderX.ToString();
        shoulder_y.Text = "Shoulder Y: " + shoulderY.ToString();

        elbow_x.Text = "Elbow X: " + elbowX.ToString();
        elbow_y.Text = "Elbow Y: " + elbowY.ToString();

        hand_x.Text = "Hand X: " + handX.ToString();
        hand_y.Text = "Hand Y: " + handY.ToString();

        Patient_HandX.Add(handX);
        Patient_HandY.Add(handY);

        Patient_ElbowX.Add(elbowX);
        Patient_ElbowY.Add(elbowY);

        Patient_ShoulderX.Add(shoulderX);
        Patient_ShoulderY.Add(shoulderY);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write a bit more about what is repeted ? I see here loop with start and end. The problem is in the loop or the loop itself ?

Comment: @Fixus The problem is that allframesready repeatsore than I want the loop to

Comment: But allfreamesready is repeated always in every frame so in every frame you got your loop. Thats too much ?

Comment: @Fixus Yes, I only want it in action for twenty reps, then want it to stop

Comment: i know this is answered, but, i see this post (http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/kinect-and-reactive-extensions-rx/) using Rx you can extract anly a sample of all events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use answer cause more writing than comment can handle :)

aleframesready action is invoked in every frame. so if here you have limit of 20 in loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < Doctor_ShoulderX.Count; i++)
```

it will be invoked from 0 to 20 every time. Imo you you should create a static boolean variable in the class. After the code go out from the loop set it to false (if on start it had true). Before you invoke the loop check if the variable is set to true. If yes invoke the loop, if no just continue